# Emails on firebase login, someone else could sign my email up without my consent?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to implement a confirmation feature for firebase password authentication, and would like to know if anyone has a good idea on implementation. (I could otherwise write a web app to manage this.)

If there is no good solution, I may just decide to forgo password based authentication, as I do not find it to be meaningful without some sort of confirmation on the user identity.

**On a side, more important note:**

*The current issue is that Firebase does not allow controls on who can write to the password auth solution that is currently provided. Combine this with the fact that there is no email confirmation feature, someone else could feasibly sign my email up. Is this how firebase is intended to have the login work?*

*After signing up, someone could log in, and use my email as the 'profile' while using the features of the application. This can be done without having confirmed that this person is actually the account holder of the email provided.*

*What if someone used my email to make terrorist threats or other, less than desirable, illegal activities?*

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've moved on by now, but for those who stumble upon this question the new firebase console does provide an email confirmation feature. At firebase.google.com, simply click on Auth on the sidebar and then click the Email Templates tab and, if you have the email sign in method enabled, you can implement the email confirmation feature there where it says Email Address Verification.